# Swift 5 reading a text file into a 2d array of Int/Doubles

Tags: arrays, swift, csv, numeric

I hope this isn't too simple a question for the group.  I am teaching myself Swift but I'm really struggling to get my head around a way to read a CSV text file containing a mixture of Int and Double values into a 2d array which sits inside a Class where each line in the array represents a line from the input file.  I have successfully loaded an 1d array of strings, each element corresponding to a line of text in the CSV file.  However I want to save time by going direct from input file to 2d array of decimals.

Comment: Without any code there is no simple question.

Comment: adding relevant code will be helpful

Comment: Swift's arrays are homogenous, that is, you can't have a mixture of different unrelated types. Luckily, for most use cases, doubles can store all values of integers, so you can just use `Double` throughout.

Comment: Please provide a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: I'm defining the target array as a mixed array e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the data.  Separate the text into lines.  Separate the lines into tokens. Convert each token to an Int or if it fails, a Double.

I assume you know how to read the files so here is an example with a static CSV string:

```
let text = """
 1,2,3.0
 4,5.0,6,z
 """

enum CustomError: Error {
  case notAnItOrADouble(String)
}

do {
  let numberRows = try text
    .split(separator: "\n")
    .map { line in
      try line.split(separator: ",").map { substring -> Any in
        let token = String(substring)
        guard let value: Any = Int(token) ?? Double(token) else {
          throw CustomError.notAnItOrADouble(token)
        }
        return value
      }
  }

  numberRows.forEach { row in
    row.forEach { number in
      print("\(number) is \(type(of: number))")
    }
  }
} catch (let error) {
  print(error)
}
```

Output:

```
1 is Int
2 is Int
3.0 is Double
4 is Int
5.0 is Double
6 is Int
```

Try putting in a string instead of an int or double and you will see that you get the error with he first unparsable token instead.

Comment: Josh, thanks for this.  I'm struggling to follow it but when I understand it in full, I think I'll have mastered this wonderful language!